# Thymeleaf URL with multiple variables

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf as template engine in my spring project.

**My Problem is**: I'm trying to submit my form to url that contains two variables, something like:

mysite/bla/{id}/bla/{id2} (two variables in url). So, I'm trying with this:

```
th:href="@{/bla/{id}/bla/{id2} (id=${object1.id}, id2=${object2.id})}"
```

The console shows the error:

*"Skipping URI variable 'id' since the request contains a bind value with the same name."* So, someone has any ideia whats happening?

Update:

I changed the path to one variable, just to make some tests, and the problem still happening. The controller is very simple:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}/bla")
    public ModelAndView salvarBug(MyObject object,
            @PathVariable("id") Long idObject1, Principal principal) {
                objectService.save(object);
                return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+idObject1);
    }
```

I updated the link in html too:

```
        <form method="POST" th:object="${object}"
            th:action="@{/{id}/bla (id=${object.id})}">
```

**The real problem:** an attribute was going null for database. Make no sense in this. I fix this.

Comment: And the two `bla`s are the same in your example?

Comment: No, just a example, they really have another name.

Comment: Can you post your controller code?  The link looks correct to me.

Comment: I add the updates in description.

Comment: I found the problem: an attribute was going null for the database, make no sense in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution uses the Standard Syntax and looks correct.  You can try this workaround with concatenation:

`<a th:href="${'/blah1/' + {object1.id} + '/blah2/' + {object2.id}}">some link</a>`

UPDATE:

Try changing the name of the variable to something other than `id`.  There's a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9349) about this that I suspect may be causing an issue.  You can also annotate with `@ModelAttribute`.  You should also make sure you're on the latest version of Spring.

Also, you can just do `@PostMapping("/{id}/bla")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this method. It worked for me

```
<a th:href="@{/this/istheurl(parameter1 = val1, parameter2 = val2) }">
```

Answer (score 1):

**The real problem:** an attribute was going null for database. Make no sense in this. I fix this.

Comment: That's an unusual error message for a null attribute.

Comment: Yes, it was an array, I've never seen it happen before.