# parsing multiple variables path from url in thymeleaf th:action

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am trying to get to the following URL in thyemleaf. This is basically a button that when clicked supposed to increment a value in the backend and turn a boolean value to true. Each of these path variables comes from a different entity which in my case I refer to them uip and pid. I tried to run the debugger in eclipse but did not even reach/hit my endpoint in my controller. Also, I am not getting a stack trace of any error other than console output with no error.

part of the `HTML`

```
    <table id="multi-color-bg" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Party Symbols</th>
                <th>Party Name</th>
                <th th:if="${#request.userPrincipal.principal.isVoted == false}">Vote Here</th>
                <th id="action" th:if="!user.isVoted" >Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each=" party : ${parties}">
                <td th:text="${party.id}">Party ID</td>
                <td th:text="${party.name}">Party Name</td>
                <td th:if="${#request.userPrincipal.principal.isVoted == false}">
                    
                    <form th:action="@{/vote/{uid}(uid=${#request.userPrincipal.principal.id}/{pid}(pid=${party.id})}" method="post">
                             
                             <button id="voted" > Vote Here</button>
                                
                             
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td class="actionButtons">
```

`Controller`

```
@PostMapping("/vote/{uid}/{pid}")
    public String vote(@PathVariable Long uid, @PathVariable Long pid) {
        Optional<User> user = userService.findById(uid);
        if(user.isPresent()) {
            User foundUser = user.get();
            foundUser.setIsVoted(true);
            userService.update(foundUser);
            
        }
        Party party = partyService.findPartyById(pid);
        if(party.getId() != null) {
            partyService.vote(pid);
        }
      return "redirect:/";
    }
```

when I click on the button I get Whitelabel error page 404 with the following URL:

`http://localhost:8080/vote/%7Buid%7D(uid=$%7B?pid=1#request.userPrincipal.principal.id}/{pid}`

Here is the console output as you can see no error is there

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_3_, user0_.created_date as created_2_3_, user0_.email as email3_3_, user0_.first_name as first_na4_3_, user0_.voted as voted5_3_, user0_.last_name as last_nam6_3_, user0_.password as password7_3_, user0_.username as username8_3_ from users user0_ where user0_.username=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_2_0_, role1_.id as id1_1_1_, role1_.role_name as role_nam2_1_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join roles role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
2022-06-13 02:50:58.062 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2022-06-13 02:50:58.062 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from 7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97
2022-06-13 02:50:58.062 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.063 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/?
2022-06-13 02:50:58.063 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@60edf337]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.063 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@60edf337]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.063 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-06-13 02:50:58.065 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /?
2022-06-13 02:50:58.066 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.066 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.066 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Loaded matching saved request http://localhost:8080/?
2022-06-13 02:50:58.067 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /?] with attributes [authenticated]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.067 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /?
Hibernate: select party0_.id as id1_0_, party0_.party_name as party_na2_0_, party0_.vote_count as vote_cou3_0_ from parties party0_
2022-06-13 02:50:58.107 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-06-13 02:50:58.124 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /css/partiesview.css
2022-06-13 02:50:58.125 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.125 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.125 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /css/partiesview.css] with attributes [permitAll]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.125 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /css/partiesview.css
2022-06-13 02:50:58.128 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-06-13 02:50:58.128 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /partiesview.js
2022-06-13 02:50:58.128 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.128 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.129 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /partiesview.js] with attributes [authenticated]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.129 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /partiesview.js
2022-06-13 02:50:58.130 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-06-13 02:50:58.132 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2022-06-13 02:50:58.132 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.132 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:50:58.133 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2022-06-13 02:50:58.176 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-06-13 02:51:01.482 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /vote/{uid}(uid=${?pid=1
2022-06-13 02:51:01.483 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:51:01.483 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:51:01.484 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [POST /vote/{uid}(uid=${?pid=1] with attributes [permitAll]
2022-06-13 02:51:01.484 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /vote/{uid}(uid=${?pid=1
2022-06-13 02:51:01.494 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-06-13 02:51:01.494 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error?pid=1
2022-06-13 02:51:01.495 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:51:01.495 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.voiceit.security.MyUserDetail@2fb87471, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7D7E807F5E7CD7CF9BF2E7C59C1E3C97], Granted Authorities=[user]]]
2022-06-13 02:51:01.495 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error?pid=1
2022-06-13 02:51:01.502 DEBUG 509262 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805112/thymeleaf-url-with-multiple-variables) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617512/passing-two-values-from-html-to-controller-using-thymeleaf-thhref) but not helping.

Comment: Pretty sure your thymeleaf for the action is faulty and should be something like `@{/vote/{uid}/{pid}(uid=${#request.userPrincipal.principal.id}, pid=${party.id})}` in your example the pid part is withing the `()` which is used for assigning variables

Comment: @Ralan I did change that but still getting the same issue, same console output as shown above!!!

Comment: The original issue is not in the console output but the fact that the url the button opens appears to not be formatted by thymeleaf, the given reply should've atleast changed the target url and as far as i know fixed it. looking at console output it should have also changed with previous comment edit as `/vote/{uid}(uid=${?pid=1` should not be possible.
For thymeleaf path variables see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-path-variables